# KnockoutJS, style binding with a 2D array?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

So I am working with a JSON object of CSS attributes/divs, something like:

```
"#myDiv": {
    "position": "absolute",
    "max-height": "225px"
  },
```

And I am binding this object to a div using KnockoutJS's style binding:

```
<!-- ko with: $root.Styles['#myDiv'] -->
     <div data-bind="style:{
         position: position,
         maxHeight: $data['max-height']
       }"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Position binds fine, and any other properties that do not have to be accessed explicitly are OK as well. Is it possible to bind something like **$data['max-height']** within a KnockoutJS style binding?

*I'd also like to note that I can succesfully bind **$data['max-height']** to a text field, but it always fails with a syntax error when binding a style.

Thoughts? :)

**Update**

For anyone still experiencing this, I am using VS 2015 with includes Browser Link by default. Disabling this feature removes all syntax errors. Add this to your web.config:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

Thanks again to @Jeroen for pointing out the error wasn't caused by KO.

Comment: Try style: { maxHeight: function($data) { return $data['max-height'] } }

Comment: No luck, still gives me a 'unrecognized expression' error. There's has to be some quirky syntax to allow this :p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've posted should work fine with styles like this:

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  Styles: {
    "#myDiv": {
      "position": "absolute",
      "max-height": "225px"
    }
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: pink;  /* to demo "max-height" is working... */
  font-size: 80px; /* to demo "max-height" is working... */
  top: 50px; /* to demo "position" is working... */
  left: 50px; /* to demo "position" is working... */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!-- ko with: $root.Styles['#myDiv'] -->
<div data-bind="style:{
         position: position,
         maxHeight: $data['max-height']
       }">X
  <br>X
  <br>X
  <br>X
  <br>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

The position is working as you can tell from the fact that `top` and `left` from the css are picked up.

The `max-height` is picked up as you can see from the pink background not going beyond 225px in height.

Comment: Odd.. So with the syntax I had and that you demonstrated it seems to work but still throws 'Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div[data-bind='style:{'. I am binding exactly the same. Maybe a character is out of place.. I will check it out.

Comment: Thanks for your help and confirming the syntax, I've got something goofy going on with nested div's and the with binding.

Comment: Glad it helped. I had not seen that error with KO before, and the exact text [doesn't seem to be in its codebase](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=unrecognized+expression) (however, [it *is* in the jQuery codebase...](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=unrecognized+expression), specifically the Sizzle bit...).

Comment: Browser Link... ><